# Is polarization cause of different permittivity of different substances?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I want to ask is whether polarization of a substance cause of different permittivity of different substances.

[If unable to get what I want to ask- 
Put differently, if a substance is prevented somehow to  get polarized (assume) and placed in electric field, then will it behave exactly as vacuum?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permitivity is one common way of expressing the polarization of a medium, so yes, polarization can be said to be the cause.

If a neutral substance could not be polarized, then if you do not look too closely the field outside of the substance would behave exactly as a vacuum.  However, if the substance is made out of electrons and protons that are somehow fixed in space, then there will be fields due to those charges.  If you look closely, you will find that the field inside the material would be non-uniform, and wildly varying.  And there will be fields outside of the medium due to these charges.  Theses external fields would decay in a "short" distance from the material, so that if you place your detector far enough away you won't be able to detect those fields.   But I think that in the spirit of your question, you would ignore those fields.

In the case of a homogeneous continuum, the situation is exactly like a vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

For example sunlight is only partially polarized after it passes through the earths atmosphere.  Light reflected off water is also somewhat polarized due to complex permittivity of water. However polarized light is also created in a laser.  Radio waves are mostly polarized from the broadcast antenna.